# RXJS: Return the manipulated value of outer observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, httpclient

I am trying to call two observables, with the response from second I manipulate the first and then return a new observable.

```
return this.http.get(requestUrl)
            .map((response: User) => {
                sessionManager.currentUser = response;
                return this.isFirstTimeUser(response.id);
            })
            .do((response: any) => {
                console.log(response);
                sessionManager.currentUser.firstTimeLogin = response === 'true';
                return Observable.create(sessionManager.currentUser);
            })
            .toPromise();
```

isFirstTimeUser(response.id) is another function that returns an observable.

```
private isFirstTimeUser(userId: number): Observable<any> {
        const requestUrl = 'someUrl';
        return this.http.get(requestUrl, {responseType: 'text'});
    }
```

All I want to do is get the user object from the first http call, make another request using the user's `id` in the second call and then after I get back the response from the second observable, I update a property of the first response and return the updated first response. How do I achieve this? What rxjs function should I be looking at?

Comment: In your example, where are you calling a second observable?

Comment: isFirstTimeUser(response.id) returns another http Observable.

Comment: checkout my updated answer

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to do? I tried to come up with the answer, but your description is not clear.

Comment: @codeepic Does the edit help?

Comment: instead of do() use switchMap()

Comment: @AnjiDhamala posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close in your example.

You want to use `switchMap` which *unsubscribes* to the incoming observable, and *subscribes* to the next observable.

```
return this.http.get(requestUrl)
        .switchMap((response: User) => {
            sessionManager.currentUser = response;
            return this.isFirstTimeUser(response.id);
        })
        .map((response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            sessionManager.currentUser.firstTimeLogin = response === 'true';
            return sessionManager.currentUser;
        })
        .toPromise();
```

The response will be passed to `isFirstTimeuser()` and the following `.map()` will be applied to the observabled returned by that function.

It's called `switchMap` because the observable returned by `this.http.get()` is *unsubscribed* and the next observable is used. This won't be a problem with `this.http.get()`, but keep in mind that `switchMap` only works for the *first* emitted value.

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The solution you're looking for is something like that:

```
getUser(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(reqUrl)
        .do((res: User) => {
            sessionManager.currentUser = res;
        })
        .switchMap((res: User) => {
            return this.isFirstTimeUser(res.id);
        })
        .do((res: any) => {
            console.log(response);
        }
        .map((res: any) => {
            sessionManager.currentUser.firstTimeLogin = res === 'true';
            return sessionManager.currentUser;
        });
}
```

Then you just need to subscribe to `getUser()` and you should be alright. It is still not the best code according to rxjs functional paradigm of pure functions. I guess using `concatMap` with projection function would get us closer to ideal, but  it will work.

The reason it's not ideal is because there's a required side effect in the first `.do()` block, we update the `sessionManager` value - a variable outside the function (a big no no in functional world) and then we access it again in `.map()` function. `concatMap` with projection function as a 2nd argument would get us around this.

Answer (score 0):

Use mergeMap

```
return this.http.get(requestUrl)
            .mergeMap((response: User) => {
                const currentUser = response;
                currentUser.firstTimeLogin = this.isFirstTimeUser(response.id) === 'true' 
                return Observable.of(currentUser);
            })
```

Comment: your example was not clear for me, so i used this one

Comment: It is not my example. It's my problem. I'm looking a solution for my particular problem as I am not too versed in rxjs. Do you think you could edit the answer to cater to my problem?

Comment: in rxjs you should NOT modify any variable except the observable emitions, here you mutate sessionManager, which is invalid in the context of RX

Comment: That's true if you do `sessionManager.currentUser = response` it's a bad practice. As it's a side effect outside of the observable stream.

Comment: `this.isFirstTimeUser(response.id) === 'true'` is never true. It returns an observable. See the OPs comments.

Comment: @cgTag It's not specified that this.isFirstTimeUser(response.id) returns an observable, if thats true, then your answer is right one.